# send uiimage to a server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Until now I send `strings` to a server with this method:

```
NSString *reqURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:];
reqURL = [reqURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:reqURL]];
NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *err = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
```

and I want to know if there is a possible to send an `UIImage` to server.

Answer (score 2):

if your image is `png` then use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to get it's data in `NSData`.

```
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myUIImage);
```

if your image is `jpg` or `jpeg` then use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to get it's data in `NSData`.

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myUIImage);
```

Check in [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation)

Check below SO post for sending `NSData` `UIImage` to server.

[Sending an image data(NSData) to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483248/sending-an-image-datansdata-to-the-server)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:-

```
    NSData *imagedata=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.editedImage)]; 
    NSString *base64string=[imagedata base64EncodedString];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/uploadBlogData.php",appUrl];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:base64string forKey:@"imagedata"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];

        NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
    NSLog(@"responseStatusString %@",[request responseString]);
```

What this code exactly does it, I have convert my image into NSData and then again encode in base 64 string.
You can also do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

and do this:

```
    -(void)uploadImage{
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

        // Upload a file on disk
        [request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg"
    forKey:@"photo"];

       // Upload an NSData instance
      [request setData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myUIImage) withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];

      [request setDelegate:self];
      [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFinished:)];
      [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadRequestFailed:)];

      [request startAsynchronous];
}
```